# Are boolean, integer and float ADTs in python?

Tags: python, abstract-data-type

I know that in some languages integers, booleans etc are simple data types, with strings, lists, queues, stacks etc being Abstract Data Types. This appears to vary between languages.

For python, would you classify boolean, integer and float as ADTs?

Comment: I wouldn't classify any implementation of any data type in any programming language as an *abstract* data type.  If you define what the integer ADT is, I might be able to tell you if an implementation is a faithful (choose your own word if you don't like faithful) implementation of the ADT but the implementation is, necessarily, concrete.

Comment: I would not say so as they are immutable, and also the set of operations or the set of values it can contain are predefined so they would not be abstract data type, but you could change the code of python, although you should not and why would you, and maybe add an operation which makes it an ADT

Comment: in python everything is a object. so defining Bool int float as ADT is No

Comment: Is there a settled definition of an ADT?

Comment: As others have said, no, but the `Integral` and `Real` abstract classes in the `numbers` package are.